# Aggregating MySQL data on hourly basis from minute-wise raw data

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table, table_1, which has data for EACH minute and looks like:

```
+---------------------+---------+
| date_time           | value   |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2015-06-05 18:00:00 | 222.663 |
| 2015-06-05 18:01:00 | 222.749 |
| 2015-06-05 18:02:00 | 222.957 |
| 2015-06-05 18:03:00 | 223.063 |
| 2015-06-05 18:04:00 | 223.117 |
+---------------------+---------+
```

I wish to fetch hourly min and max values. Something like:

```
+---------------------+---------+
| date_time           | value   |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2015-06-05 18:10:00 | 200.663 |
| 2015-06-05 18:45:00 | 222.749 |
| 2015-06-05 19:10:00 | 190.957 |
| 2015-06-05 19:33:00 | 400.063 |
+---------------------+---------+
```

Currently I am creating a for loop in PHP and runs a query for EACH hour. However, it is obviously not the best way to do it, and is thus VERY TIME CONSUMING. For example:

```
for($temp = $st; $temp <= $et; $temp = $temp + 60){//looping for each hour

 $sql1 = "select * from table_1 where value in 
 (select max(value) from table_1 
 where date_time >= '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$st)."' 
 and date_time < '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$temp)."' ) 
 and date_time >= '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$st)."' 
 and date_time < '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$temp)."' limit 1";

 $rs1 = mysql_query($sql1);

 $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs1)
 $val1 = $row1['value']; 
 $date1 = $row1['date_time'];

}
```

Comment: Floor Unix time stamp and group by that

Comment: @Strawberry do you mean this?  `select DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') h, min(value), max(value) from thetable group by h`

Comment: @splash58 thanks. I tried and got the following: `+---------------------+------------+------------+
| h                   | min(value) | max(value) |
+---------------------+------------+------------+
| 2015-06-05 18:00:00 |      221.7 |     223.22 |
| 2015-06-05 19:00:00 |    221.838 |    222.697 |
| 2015-06-05 20:00:00 |    221.546 |    222.444 |`. Two questions: **1.** How to do the same thing for intervals like 6 hours or 15 minutes. **2.** The result above does NOT show the original time stamp corresponding to the min and max values. How to get those. Thanks.

Comment: i've written that as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anawer for the question

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') h, min(value), max(value)
    from thetable 
  group by h
```

**1. How to do the same thing for intervals like 6 hours or 15 minutes.**

for 15 minute interval:

```
select date_time, min(value), max(value) 
     from t1 
  group by round(unix_timestamp(date_time)/(15 * 60))
```

For 6 hours interval change to (6 * 60 * 60)

**2. The result above does NOT show the original time stamp corresponding to the min and max values. How to get those.**

Such query give you what you want. But if, for example, there are some minimum values in an interval, get so many rows how many such values

```
select date_time, value 
    from t1, 
         (select DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') h, 
                 min(value) min, max(value) max 
              from t1 
            group by h
         ) t 
  where value in (min, max) 
    and DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') = h
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Last question. How to group for intervals like 6 hours or 15 minutes (your solution works perfect for hourly interval)

Comment: Thanks. I am using result 2 as it gives me the original timestamps. However, I tried implementing it for 15 M interval. It is returning only two values (one min and one max). I want values for EVERY interval of 15 minutes. So, there should be 4 * 2 = 8 values reported for every hour.