# aggregating mysql data from minute-wise raw data

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table, table_1, which has data for EACH minute and looks like:

```
+---------------------+---------+
| date_time           | value   |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2015-06-05 18:00:00 | 222.663 |
| 2015-06-05 18:01:00 | 222.749 |
| 2015-06-05 18:02:00 | 222.957 |
| 2015-06-05 18:03:00 | 223.063 |
| 2015-06-05 18:04:00 | 223.117 |
+---------------------+---------+
```

I wish to fetch min and max values for every 15 min interval (or any other interval; customizable). **Desired output:**

```
+---------------------+---------+
| date_time           | value   |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2015-06-05 18:10:00 | 200.663 | (min between 18:00 and 18:14)
| 2015-06-05 18:13:00 | 222.749 | (max between 18:00 and 18:14)
| 2015-06-05 18:17:00 | 190.957 | (min between 18:15 and 18:29)
| 2015-06-05 18:33:00 | 400.063 | (max between 18:15 and 18:29)
+---------------------+---------+
```

I am currently using the following solution:

```
select date_time, value 
    from table_1, 
         (select date_time h, 
                 min(value) min, max(value) max 
              from table_1 where date_time >= '2015-06-05 18:00:00' and date_time < '2015-06-05 19:00:00' 
            group by round(unix_timestamp(date_time)/(15 * 60))
         ) t 
  where value in (min, max) 
    and date_time = h
```

The solution is based on:
[Aggregating MySQL data on hourly basis from minute-wise raw data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421110/aggregating-mysql-data-on-hourly-basis-from-minute-wise-raw-data)

However, the current solution gives me only two values (one min and one max). I wish to have ALL the min and max values from ALL the 15 minute intervals, as per example shown above.

Comment: Why don't you want to think at least two minitutes? :( select date_time, value 
    from t1, 
         (select round(unix_timestamp(date_time)/(15 * 60)) h, 
                 min(value) min, max(value) max 
              from t1 
            group by h
         ) t 
  where value in (min, max) 
    and round(unix_timestamp(date_time)/(15 * 60)) = h

Comment: @splash58 sorry mate, I am still a beginner and was not able to work out the right solution. Thanks for the solution. BTW, I replaced round() with floor().

Comment: @luvlogic : can you plz create some sample data at http://sqlfiddle.com/ and share us the link.

Comment: @splash58 i want to mark this an answer. Pls post your original comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is common result with author of the question :)

```
select date_time, value 
    from t1, 
         (select floor(unix_timestamp(date_time)/(15 * 60)) h, 
                 min(value) min, max(value) max 
              from t1 
            group by h
         ) t 
  where value in (min, max) 
    and floor(unix_timestamp(date_time)/(15 * 60)) = h
```

Comment: Sorry for being a pain. If there are more than one values which are same as max (or min) value in an interval, ALL of them are being reported. I want only one max and one min value in the interval. I tried putting limit in the select query, but that does not work correctly.

Comment: I wrote about that in my 1st answer. When be near a comp, shall write

Comment: @luvlogic  add tail: `group by floor(unix_timestamp(date_time)/(15 * 60)), value`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet gives max and min for every 15 minutes interval. You can replace 15 by any integer that divides 60 perfectly.

```
    select b.date_time,b.value
 from
 table_1 b
 join (select  min(a.value) minv, max(a.value) maxv, date_sub(a.date_time,INTERVAL second(a.date_time)+
                (minute(a.date_time)-minute(a.date_time) div 15)
                *60 second) partition_interval
from table_1 a
 group by partition_interval) temp
on temp.partition_interval=date_sub(b.date_time,INTERVAL second(b.date_time)+
                (minute(b.date_time)-minute(b.date_time) div 15)
                *60 second)
                and b.value in(temp.minv,temp.maxv)
group by temp.partition_interval,b.value
```

Code Edit 1:
Replaced `@date_time` by `date_time`

The code is giving result as per expectation.

Kindly verify at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd668/16

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, the code returns only one set of values. I need values for each interval.

Comment: @luvlogic : It will give data(1 row) for each interval if data exists at least one row in the particular interval.

Comment: @luvlogic : I regret for the delay in response. I have updated the code. by replacing `@date_time` by `date_time`.

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. However, I see that the original timestamps are lost. min and max values show up in a single record against a timestamp which is not corresponding to the min / max value. Thanks all the same. esp for sqlFiddle.